# Regex expression Giving all letters

Tags: regex, tableau-api

I need all groups of 4 capital letters in a string.

So I am using `REGEXP_REPLACE([Description],'\b(?![A-Z]{4}\b)\w+\b',' ')` 
 in `Tableau` to replace all small letters and extra characters. I want to get only instances of capital letters with 4 string length.

By google I got to know i cannot use Regex_extract (Since /g is not supported)

My String:

`"The following trials have no study data-available, in the RBM mart. It appears as is this because they were . In y HIWEThe trials currently missing data are:
JADA, JPBD, JVCS, JADQ, JVDI, JVDO, JVTZ"`

I have written `[^A-Z]{4}/g`.

I want:

`HIWE JADA JPBD JVCS JADQ JVDI JVDO JVTZ`

But this is also giving me single capital letter and space included.

Thanks

Comment: What does [a-zA-Z]*$  indicate?

Comment: I guess you want to extract all *words* other than 4-uppercase letter words? Try [`\b(?![A-Z]{4}\b)\w+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/gI2fC0/1)

Comment: Maybe replacing what you do not want by empty space? Also, what language/tool are you using?

Comment: [^A-Z] says to capture ANY character that aren't A-Z

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It is including spaces too...

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes : I am using Tableau and i am using Regex_replace funcation

Comment: @user1078682: Please clarify how you are using the regex, share the exact code.

Comment: Why not use `REGEXP_EXTRACT(string, pattern)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : I mean it is including spaces between words and also it is including ' ? , ! ;  'and this kind of stuff, is there a way to remove them?
Thanks

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : It is not giving all instances, it is matching only first instance as tableau doesnt support  /g (Global)option Please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: And how does replace works then? What do you want to remove from the input string? Try the opposite regex: [`\b[A-Z]{4}\b|\W+`](https://regex101.com/r/gI2fC0/2). NOTE that you should specify how you are using the regex and what  exactly you need to match before posting the question. That way, your question would look nicer and could get you some rep points.

Comment: Ok here is my question : I need all 4 letter capital letter, so I am using REGEXP_REPLACE([Description],'\b(?![A-Z]{4}\b)\w+\b',' ')  in Tableau to replace all small letters and extra charecters so , that i would be getting only 4 capital letter words. By google I got to know i cannot use Regex_extract. The above worked by giving special charecters ? how to remove both?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes :Tableau is a reporting tool and it doesnt support /g

Comment: @user1078682: Tried `REGEXP_REPLACE([Description],'\b[A-Z]{4}\b|\W+',' ')` already?

Comment: Nop \b[A-Z]{4}\b|\W+ is giving me small letters too... remember I am uisng negative so we cannot use [A-Z] I have tried [^A-Z]{4} it is giving single capital letters also

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide a clear example of what a regex should match inside the input string.

Comment: Maybe if _positive lookbehinds_ works: [`((?<=[A-Z]{4})|^).*?(?=[A-Z]{4}\b|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/rC0vE9/2)

Comment: My String is the above mentioned : I need only capital letters with 4 string length:So i am repplacing all other letters, special charecters  with a blank; That what REGEX_Replace does, my task is to find all such letters and special charecters so that it will replace with blank and give me only 4 letter words, Let me know if you still ahve questions

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Close but no cigar ;) - Your RE misses the `HIWE`.

Comment: Try this then: [`((?<=[A-Z]{4})|^).*?(?=[A-Z]{4}|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/rC0vE9/3)

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes : Yup Close... enough

Comment: Did it help? If so, I can answer explaining the regex ;)

Comment: yes please explain me and I will verify and let you thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/rC0vE9/3):

```
((?<=[A-Z]{4})|^).*?(?=[A-Z]{4}|$)
```

Explaining:

```
(                    # one of:
    ^                # the starting position
  |                  # or
    (?<=[A-Z]{4})    # any position after four upper letters
)                    # 
.*?                  # match anything till the first:
(?=                  # position which in front
    [A-Z]{4}         # has four upper letters
  |                  # or
    $                # is the string's end
)                    #
```

Any doubt feel free to ask :)

Comment: For this  String your case is working for a string  like 

 "H9X-MC-GBGE: Duplicate Blood Pressure (Within Visit)
The analytic is listing items that aren't true duplicates. ."

And when there is not match at all it is not returning null it is giving the entire desrption..

Comment: @user1078682. Sorry, I didn't understand, can you update the question with the exactly input and (desired) output? I'll be back soon ;(

Comment: @user1078682. I'm back again ;) ... Just curious, what have you modified? Also, if this answer helped, you can can check the green mark to accept it ;)